# stopwatch html keyEvent listener to keyup and keydown

Tags: javascript, html, event-listener, keylistener, stopwatch

I want to make a stopwatch that starts while `spacebar` is up, and stops when `spacebar` is down.

However, it starts right after i have stopped it because the start function is called when the `spacebar` is up.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

```js
window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    if (elapsedTime == 0) {
      if (status == "started") {
        clearInterval(timerInterval)
        stop();
        status = "stopped";
      } else {
        start();
        status = "started";
      }
    } else {
      reset();
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Your question is unlogic, and the code is incomplete

Comment: if elapsed time is ZERO how would you have it as started?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let counter = 0;
let counterInterval;
let counter_running = false;

function start() {
  counter_running = true;
  counterInterval = setInterval(() => {
    counter++;
    console.log(counter)
  }, 1000);
}

function stop() {
  counter_running = false;
  clearInterval(counterInterval);
}

window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 32 && !counter_running) {
    start();
  }
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode === 32) {
    stop();
  }
});
```

You should change the code to listen for keydown on the spacebar. This way when pressed down, the start function will be called, and on keyup, when the spacebar is released the function stop will be called.

I have added a check if the interval is running, as otherwise it would keep starting intervals and there is only 1 interval needed and the keyup will only stop one.

Something like this simplified version - this should be modified to make the correct changes and include the reset function as you want it to work.